# Notification icon not showing properly

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to set a new notification icon for my app, however i cannot seem to make it work. I receive the notifications, but instead of my logo i see a black/grey circle in the status bar like this:

[image: Status bar]

My MessageService looks like this:

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("notification_msg_id", remoteMessage.getData().get("my_msg_id"));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder
            = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
     .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_my_logo)
     .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
     .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack))
     .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

I generated the small icon with [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) (pretty great) tool and as you can see Android Studio is able to find the image in every size needed:

[image]

Here's my SDK versions:

[image: used sdk versions]

I read earlier that there might be some problems with caching of drawables, i've tried invalidating every cache and cleaned/builded the project as well.
I've also tried different image files as well as xml vector drawables.

Do you guys have any idea what i'm doing wrong or how i can troubleshoot the issue further?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is the icon i am trying to use in xxxhdpi-v11 format (it's white you probably need to click it to see it):

[image]

Comment: post your icon too it seems like issue with ic_stat_my_logo.png

Comment: put small icon it show it because if large icon not fit then it show black.

Comment: @AndroidTeam So it's showing black because the large icon doesn't fit - not because the small doesn't?

Comment: @Taranmeet I've posted the icon now. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you got the same logo name in each folder maybe the one needed by the notifcation is different as notification icon must be of 24x24 dp

Comment: I have it in 24x24, 36x36, 48x48 and 72x72, so i don't think it's missing a size. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Notification icons must be entirely white for API 21 et later. try using this:

```
notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
```

Comment: Changing the color to white changes the color of the circle on my emulator, but unfortunately it still doesn't show the icon.